# Grails plugin enconding: backwards compatibility

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm developing a `grails plugin` that adds a new taglib and renders a template.

My problem is that this template outputs a `JSON` and I need it not to be encoded.

If I use the `raw()` function it works fine but this is not compatible with grails versions < 2.3.x.

Previous versions works if I use scriptlets (<%= %>) but they are escaped in newer versions by default([..] scriptlet = 'html'[..]).

**Is there any solution that works in all versions?**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line in your template:

```
<%@page expressionCodec="none" %>
```

Comment: It works but apparently that page directive does not exist until grails 2.3.x